# Can my laptop pick up CB radio frequencies?

Tags: rfi, frequency, citizens-band

I was on my laptop watching a show and I paused to look something up and since there was no sound I could hear a voice talking. It sounded distorted like it was coming over a radio and I couldn't make out what was saying. There does not appear to be any unusual process running on the laptop. As I listen more it sounds like the man is having a whole conversation with someone else. There is a truck stop right by their house. Is it possible that my laptop is picking up a CB radio frequency?

Comment: Is it your laptop internal speakers, or do you have external speakers connected to your computer?

Comment: @Juancho no i can hear him through my ear buds

Answer (score 9):

Yes, very strong radio signals can be picked up by just about any device with a speaker and a transistor in it. The transistor acts as a [rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier), forming a crude [envelope detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector). Amplitude modulated voice can be heard quite clearly, single-sideband modulated voice is quite garbled but often still somewhat intelligible.

No cause for alarm: it won't damage your laptop and it's nothing malicious going on. Probably just some trucker with an illegal CB amplifier.